# Why is the content of new Function(...) not compiled in these illustrations?

Tags: javascript

I happen to go through this [article](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index.html).

Consider the snippet:

```
function createMyFunction(myOperator)
{
  return new Function("a", "b", "return a" + myOperator + "b;");
}

var add=createMyFunction("+");                // creates "add" function
var subtract=createMyFunction("-");           // creates "subtract" function
var multiply=createMyFunction("*");           // created "multiply" function

// test the functions
alert("result of add="+add(10,2));            // result is 12
alert("result of substract="+subtract(10,2)); // result is 8
alert("result of multiply="+multiply(10,2));  // result is 20
alert(add);
```

That interesting example creates 3 different functions during ***runtime*** by passing a parameter which will be used ***to build a new Function***.

The author mentions

> Since the compiler has no way of knowing what the final code will look
>   like, the content of new Function(...) is not compiled

I just didn't get it. Can someone please elaborate by extending a bit?

Comment: i'm guessing that they mean that it won't be compiled into code when the script is first parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author doesn't want to say that the function is not compiled - since we are running it, is has to be.

He is trying to express that the code of a `new Function("…")` is parsed and compiled at the time when `new Function()` is called - in contrast to functions created using function expressions or declarations, which are compiled when your script is parsed.

He makes his point when he goes on:

> … and is potentially slower than the other ways of declaring functions.

So you should avoid calling `new Function()` again and again, it'll be slower than creating function expressions in a closure - they are compiled only once. Depending on the sophistication of your JS engine, the difference can be substantial.

Comment: @Bargi: +1, upvoted for "new Function("…") is parsed and compiled at the time when new Function() is called".Thank you very much indeed.